# Inner class property not seen in visualforce dynamic component

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-apex, dynamic-vf-component

**Apex Class**

```
public class outterClass(){
    // set properties
    public List<innerClass> inners {get; set;}

    outterClass(){
        // set inners list values
        inners = new public List<innerClass>{ inner1, inner2};
        for(innerClass inner : inners){
            inner.repeatService = new Component.Apex.Repeat(); // add some value in repeatService 
        }

    }
    
    public class innerClass(){
       // set properties
       public Component.Apex.Repeat repeatService {get; set;}
       public Component.Apex.Repeat getRepeatService(){
           System.debug('Execute get...');
           return this.repeatService;
       }
    }
}
```

**Visualforce page**

```
   <apex:page controller="outterClass">
       <apex:repeat var="inner" value="{!inners}">
           <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!inner.repeatService}"/>
       </apex:repeat>
   </apex:page>
```

*getRepeatService is not executed...Why?*

Comment: Its because you have already defined getter for that. the First line in the `innerClass`. Also, you have several syntax errors in your code.

Comment: I don't think the error come from the definition of the getter, because i tried to remove the getter but i still get the same result... For the syntax errors, i was just trying to abstract my class.

Answer (score 0):

I just added **invokeAfterAction="true"** to my visualforce component and it works.